# Async File Upload not updating Update Panel in Firefox

Tags: updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I’m using the Async File Upload control from the Ajax Control Toolkit (I’ve tried versions 3.0 and 3.5 for asp.net 3.5). When the file upload is complete I update some text fields in a simple asp:updatepanel. For some reason this works fine in Chrome but it won’t update in Firefox. I have exhaustively tried many different solutions including setting the updatepanels update mode to conditional to no avail. It works fine on Chrome but just won’t change anything on Firefox inside the updatepanel.